# Eclipse layout for table and two buttons

Tags: eclipse, swt

I am trying to lay out a form for an Eclipse editor and running into a few problems.

The idea is to have a page which contains 2 sections - the left hand section contains a table and two buttons. The table should line up with the top of the section and expand right to the bottom. I want the buttons to sit to the right of the table in the section with each button under the other and for them to align with the top of the table.

Does anyone know what settings for GridLayouts I need to make this work? I've tried every combination I can think of with no luck.

The closest I can get ends up with the second button at the bottom of the page.

Here is an excerpt of my code so far:-

```
Section section = toolkit.createSection(sashForm, ExpandableComposite.TITLE_BAR | ExpandableComposite.EXPANDED | ExpandableComposite.NO_TITLE_FOCUS_BOX);
section.setText("All Items");

Composite client = toolkit.createComposite(section);
section.setClient(client);

client.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

Table table = toolkit.createTable(client, SWT.NULL);
table.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL | GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING));

TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(table);

Button addButton = toolkit.createButton(client, "Add", SWT.PUSH);
addButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL | GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING));

Button removeButton = toolkit.createButton(client, "Remove", SWT.PUSH);
removeButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL | GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SWT Layout Tutorials](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) it has a good section on GridLayout.

You will want to use the `GridData.verticalSpan` for the table to get it to cover two rows. That should put the two buttons on the right. But then the buttons will take the same space as the table which is probably not what you want, so you may need to give vertical size hint to the table.